# Why is 'import' an invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to import a file containing questions, is there anything else I can do?

```
#Main Menu
print("Thank you for registering, Welcome to the main menu!")
print("Please Choose a Subject")
print("Geography - 1")
print("News - 2")
print("Tv/Movie - 3")

Option1 = int(input("Please enter your selected number:")

if Option1 == 1
              import Option1
```

The last import gives an invalid syntax

Comment: Count the parentheses: `int(input("Please enter your selected number:")`. Count the colons: `if Option1 == 1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis (`')`) at the end of the input, and a colon (`:`) at the end of the `if` statement:

```
Option1 = int(input("Please enter your selected number:"))
# Was missing -------------------------------------------^

if Option1 == 1:
    # Here ----^
    import Option1
```